# mysterious rtm abort using haswell tsx

Tags: c++, x86-64, transactional-memory, intel-tsx

I'm experimenting with the tsx extensions in haswell, by adapting an existing medium-sized (1000's of lines) codebase to using GCC transactional memory extensions (which indirectly are using haswell tsx in this machine) instead of coarse grained locks. I am using GCC's transactional_memory extensions, not writing my own _xbegin / _xend directly.  I am using the ITM_DEFAULT_METHOD=htm

I'm having issues getting it to work fast enough because I get high rates of hardware transaction abort for mysterious reasons. As shown below, these aborts are not due to conflicts nor due to capacity limitations.

Here is the perf command I used to quantify the failure rate and underlying causes:

```
perf stat \
 -e cpu/event=0x54,umask=0x2,name=tx_mem_abort_capacity_write/ \
 -e cpu/event=0x54,umask=0x1,name=tx_mem_abort_conflict/ \
 -e cpu/event=0x5d,umask=0x1,name=tx_exec_misc1/ \
 -e cpu/event=0x5d,umask=0x2,name=tx_exec_misc2/ \
 -e cpu/event=0x5d,umask=0x4,name=tx_exec_misc3/ \
 -e cpu/event=0x5d,umask=0x8,name=tx_exec_misc4/ \
 -e cpu/event=0x5d,umask=0x10,name=tx_exec_misc5/ \
 -e cpu/event=0xc9,umask=0x1,name=rtm_retired_start/ \
 -e cpu/event=0xc9,umask=0x2,name=rtm_retired_commit/ \
 -e cpu/event=0xc9,umask=0x4,name=rtm_retired_aborted/pp \
 -e cpu/event=0xc9,umask=0x8,name=rtm_retired_aborted_misc1/ \
 -e cpu/event=0xc9,umask=0x10,name=rtm_retired_aborted_misc2/ \
 -e cpu/event=0xc9,umask=0x20,name=rtm_retired_aborted_misc3/ \
 -e cpu/event=0xc9,umask=0x40,name=rtm_retired_aborted_misc4/ \
 -e cpu/event=0xc9,umask=0x80,name=rtm_retired_aborted_misc5/ \ 
./myprogram -th 1 -reps 3000000
```

So, the program runs some code with transactions in it 30 million times. Each request involves one transaction gcc `__transaction_atomic` block.  There is only one thread in this run.

This particular `perf` command captures most of the relevant tsx performance events described in the [Intel software developers manual vol 3](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html).

The output from `perf stat` is the following:

```
             0 tx_mem_abort_capacity_write                                  [26.66%]
             0 tx_mem_abort_conflict                                        [26.65%]
    29,937,894 tx_exec_misc1                                                [26.71%]
             0 tx_exec_misc2                                                [26.74%]
             0 tx_exec_misc3                                                [26.80%]
             0 tx_exec_misc4                                                [26.92%]
             0 tx_exec_misc5                                                [26.83%]
    29,906,632 rtm_retired_start                                            [26.79%]
             0 rtm_retired_commit                                           [26.70%]
    29,985,423 rtm_retired_aborted                                          [26.66%]
             0 rtm_retired_aborted_misc1                                    [26.75%]
             0 rtm_retired_aborted_misc2                                    [26.73%]
    29,927,923 rtm_retired_aborted_misc3                                    [26.71%]
             0 rtm_retired_aborted_misc4                                    [26.69%]
           176 rtm_retired_aborted_misc5                                    [26.67%]

  10.583607595 seconds time elapsed
```

As you can see from the output:

- The `rtm_retired_start` count is 30 million (matches input to program)
- The `rtm_retired_abort` count is about the same (no commits at all)
- The `abort_conflict` and `abort_capacity` counts are 0, so these are not the reasons. Also, recall it is only one thread running, conflicts should be rare.
- The only actual leads here are the high values of `tx_exec_misc1` and `rtm_retired_aborted_misc3`, which are somewhat similar in description.

The Intel manual (vol 3) defines `rtm_retired_aborted_misc3` counters:

> code: C9H 20H
>
> > mnemonic: RTM_RETIRED.ABORTED_MISC3
> >
> > > description: Number of times an RTM execution aborted due to HLE unfriendly instructions.

The definition for `tx_exec_misc1` has some similar words:

> code: 5DH 01H
>
> > mnemonic: TX_EXEC.MISC1
> >
> > > description: Counts the number of times a class of instructions that may cause a transactional abort was executed. Since this is the count of execution, it may not always cause a transactional abort.

I checked the assembly location for the aborts using perf record/ perf report using high precision (PEBS) support for `rtm_retired_aborted`. The location has a `mov` instruction from register to register.  No weird instruction names seen nearby.

Update:

Here are two things I've tried since then:

1)  the tx_exec_misc1 and rtm_retired_aborted_misc3 signature we we see here can be obtained, for example, by a dummy block of the form

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++){
  __transaction_atomic{
    _xabort(1);
  }
}
```

or one of the form

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++){
  __transaction_atomic{
    printf("hello");
    fflush(stdout);
  }
}
```

In both cases, the perf counters look similar to what I see. However, in both cases the `perf report` for `-e cpu/tx-abort/`  points to the intuitively correct assembly lines: an `xabort` instruction for the first example and a `syscall` one for the second one.  In the real codebase, the perf report points to a stack push right at the start of a function:

```
           :    00000000004167e0 <myns::myfun()>:
    100.00 :      4167e0:       push   %rbp
      0.00 :      4167e1:       mov    %rsp,%rbp
      0.00 :      4167e4:       push   %r15
```

I have also run the same command under the intel software development emulator. It turns out that the problem goes away in that case: I get no aborts as far as the application is concerned.

Comment: Could you post your transactional loop?

Comment: Hi Matthew. Unfortunately its a somewhat large loop (spans multiple function calls, some of the functions are textually large, though the actual execution path need not be).

Comment: Is it possible for you to start cutting down the loop to see what's triggering this? This sounds like an accidental system call somewhere... though your perf results seem a bit bizarre.

Comment: I will try to, will be back in a few days. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Though it's been the case for a while, I found this unanswered question while searching, so here's the answer: This is a hardware bug in Haswell and early Broadwell chips.

The particular hardware erratum assigned by Intel is [HSW136](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/specification-updates/xeon-e3-1200v3-spec-update.pdf), and is not fixable using microcode updates. Indeed, I think it was in stepping 4 that the feature was no longer reported as available by the `cpuid` instruction, even when there was (faulty) silicon on the chip to implement it.

Comment: Microcode updates have disabled TSX in Broadwell as well.  And due to TAA vulnerabilities, most Skylake-family CPUs also have HLE disabled in microcode, with RTM always aborting.  (Or the OS can set a bit to not advertize the useless "feature") 
 https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000059422/processors.html . 
 And the feature has been removed from Ice Lake.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transactional_Synchronization_Extensions#History_and_bugs